# how to create a matrix for the number 0 in this code?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi guys, I have a homework assignment to draw pyramids of a given height. Below are examples for height = 2 and height = 3:

```
.....         .....
.....         .....
.....         ..x..
..X..         .xxx.
.XXX. n = 2   xxxxx n = 3
```

Here is the code I am using. My problem is getting the 0 to work:

```
heights = [3,4,0,5,2]

def buildPyramid(height):
    base = 2 * height - 1
    grid = []

    if height == 0:
        pass

    else:
        for xnum in range(base, 0, -2):
            # Determine the number of dots
            dots = int((base - xnum)/2)

            # Create new row in the grid
            line = ['.']*dots + ['X']*xnum + ['.']*dots

            # insert new row
            grid.insert(0, line)

        #Add 'sky' rows
        for i in range(5 - height):
            grid.insert(0, ['.']*base)
    return grid

# Print pyramids.
def print_grid(grid):

    # 1. Create all pyramids and add all of them to a list
    # 2. For 5 rows
        # 2b print the row from p0, p1, p2, p3, p4

    for pyr in grid:
        for row in pyr:
            print (" ".join(row))
pyramidList = []

for h in heights:
    pyramidList.append( buildPyramid(h) )

print_grid(pyramidList)
```

Comment: can someone please help this is an assignment i have to submit tonight and i only want help with the last step.

Comment: come on guys please i need your help by doing the 0 the rest works you can try it your self

Comment: You might get more help if you explained what you were trying to do, rather than just dumping your code. Can you explain what the output is supposed to be? How does a zero in the input change that? Stack Overflow is not here to do your homework for you, but we can help you with specific problems if you explain them.

Comment: . . . . .
. . . . .
. . X . .
. X X X .
X X X X X
. . . . . . .
. . . X . . .
. . X X X . .
. X X X X X .
X X X X X X X
. . . . X . . . .
. . . X X X . . .
. . X X X X X . .
. X X X X X X X .
X X X X X X X X X
. . .
. . .
. . .
. X .
X X X 
my zero in the code isn't working and if you can help me figure it out that would be perfect

Comment: i can't add an image to the question because i dont have enough reputation

Comment: If you edit that output into the question, it will let you format it properly. Just indent each line by four spaces, or highlight the text and click on the "code" button (which looks like `{}`). Please describe your issue in words though too, at a minimum saying "here's my code ... here's what it outputs ... here's what it should be outputting, but is not ...".

Comment: i tried indenting but it wasn't working it print them out in that format so what i am trying to do is
this is an example for number 3
{.....
.....
..X..
.XXX.
XXXXX}
and the zero should print out
{.
.
.
.
.}

Answer (score 0):

How can you build a pyramid of height 0? Well, you can simply output a grid of periods to indicate it's not filled. To do this, you need to handle the height == 0 condition, which you're simply passing over in your code. Here's what it should probably look like:

```
def buildPyramid(height):
    base = 2 * height - 1
    grid = []
    if height <= 0:  # Handle a negative or zero height.
        # Use a 5x5 grid of emptiness (periods)
        return ['.'*5] * 5
    else:
        for xnum in range(base, 0, -2):
            # Determine the number of dots
            dots = int((base - xnum)/2)
            # Create new row in the grid
            line = ['.']*dots + ['X']*xnum + ['.']*dots
            # insert new row
            grid.insert(0, line)
        #Add 'sky' rows
        for i in range(5 - height):
            grid.insert(0, ['.']*base)
    return grid
```

Doing this, your output now looks like this:

```
>>> print_grid(pyramidList)
. . . . .
. . . . .
. . X . .
. X X X .
X X X X X
. . . . . . .
. . . X . . .
. . X X X . .
. X X X X X .
X X X X X X X
. . . . .
. . . . .
. . . . .
. . . . .
. . . . .
. . . . X . . . .
. . . X X X . . .
. . X X X X X . .
. X X X X X X X .
X X X X X X X X X
. . .
. . .
. . .
. X .
X X X
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to unindent the bit of your code that adds the "sky" rows so that it gets run unconditionally, rather than only for hights of greater than one. Then you just need to fix up the `base` variable to have a meaningful value for a zero-height pyramid. Something like:

```
def buildPyramid(height):
    grid = []

    if height ==0:
        base = 1                      # added this line, replacing "pass"

    else:
        base = 2 * height - 1         # moved this down a bit

        for xnum in range(base, 0, -2):

            # Determine the number of dots
            dots = int((base - xnum)/2)

            # Create new row in the grid
            line = ['.']*dots + ['X']*xnum + ['.']*dots

            # insert new row
            grid.insert(0, line)

    #Add 'sky' rows
    for i in range(5 - height):                           # unindented these lines
        grid.insert(0, ['.']*base)


    return grid
```

One further improvement (unrelated to the issue with zero-height) would be to change your code so that you can use `grid.append(line)` rather than `grid.insert(0, line)`. Appending to a list is (on average) a constant time operation, while inserting at the start requires copying the whole list. One possible solution is to build the list upside down (simply replacing the `insert` calls with `append` calls) and then reversing the list at the end, before returning it. Another option would be to add the sky rows first (using `append`), then append the pyramid rows afterwards with a loop that counts up rather than down: `for xnum in range(1, base+1, 2)`.